# Is it possible to customize a slider via css in Codename One?

Tags: css, codenameone

My app features a progress bar which background and thumb Image need to be changed. I found that the thumb image could be changed via a constant in the designer but which I could not find in the #Constants paragraph of [the page on CSS selectors](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css/wiki/Supported-CSS-Selectors). 
I tried to change the slider UIID to the one I created in the css file like this

```
MyStyle {
background-image: url(pics/whatever.png);
cn1-background-type: cn1-image-scaled-fit;
cn1-source-dpi: 320;
}
```

but only the image appears I can't see the progress indicator (eg `mySlider.setProgress(50)`).

Can it be done and if so how ?

*Please note : I read mission 2 of CN1 bootcamp about CSS styling but could not find slider styling.*

**EDIT September 18th 2017**

Following Shai's advice, I set the MyTheme and MyThemeFull with different background images. Indeed MyTheme is always drawn completely in the background and MyThemeFull is drawn bit after bit while the progress is increasing. So when the progress reaches 100% MyThemeFull background image is shown completely. 
**The cursor (thumb) image can be set via Slider.setThumbImage().**

Any help or links to resource material  appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Slider` has two UIID's: `Slider` & `SliderFull`. Which are drawn one on top of the other to produce the slider effect.

If you change the UIID they become `MyStyle` & `MyStyleFull` and you need to customize both.

Comment: Thanks Shai, would you mind elaborating on the settings that can be customized ? What I want to acheive is a background picture (done with MyStyle) with a custom thumb image. When I set a picture in MyStyleFull I don't see the picture on top of the slider.

Comment: Ok I could not see the picture of MyThemeFull because progress was 0. Now I am trying to set the theme constant sliderThumbImage but the cursor still does not appear.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how I could miss that. There is indeed a `Slider.setThumbImage()` method that can do what I want to achieve.

Comment: I think we hide it in non-editable sliders out of the assumption that the thumb is used when dragging editable elements

Comment: We wrote simultaneously! I've just checked and I could get it work with `setThumbImage` even with a non-editable slider which is perfect!