# Is that possible I can generate this progress bar by a Slider component?

Tags: codenameone

I have a gradient progress bar with grids and symbols on it
Is that possible that I can do it with a slider component?
If it is possible, would you give some direction to do it?
Or do I have to draw it from scratch?

[image]

Comment: Please try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159400/is-it-possible-to-customize-a-slider-via-css-in-codename-one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803479/slider-in-codenameone

Comment: The UI is a bit unclear. I don't see the widget that's dragged. It's unclear if one can pick the middle elements etc. Assuming this isn't I'd just implement this as radio buttons in a layered layout with an image or a slider. Both would be within respective table layouts to ensure perfect alignment of the elements.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear.  I revised the UI by adding a widget. The widget can be dragged on one of the 5 points(short, conserve....). I have thunk about using a tablelayout. But it looks not good.

Comment: What doesn't look good with the table layout? You need to define the constraints perfectly and break things down correctly. The slider will be problematic for the background image since the steps will need to be perfectly aligned. Unfortunately on the left side you have extra space. You could theoretically use it only to position the arrow (as a thumb) but it might be challenging to align it with the background image. It will solve the problem of dragging though.